# Create columns based on key-value pairs in a string in BigQuery

Tags: google-bigquery

I have a BigQuery table that looks like this, where `response_group` is a string

| id | response_group |
| --- | --- |
| A1 | [{"Answer":"blue","Question":"what's your favourite colour?"},{"Answer":"dogs","Question":"do you prefer dogs or cats?"},{"Answer":"coffee", "Question":"do you prefer tea or coffee?"}] |
| A2 | [{"Answer":"green","Question":"what's your favourite colour?"},{"Answer":"Superman","Question":"who's your favourite superhero?"},{"Answer":"coffee", "Question":"do you prefer tea or coffee?"}] |

As shown here, not all of the questions are the same for each ID.

What I'd like to create is a table like this

| id | what's your favourite colour? | do you prefer dogs or cats? | do you prefer tea or coffee? | who's your favourite superhero? |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A1 | blue | dogs | coffee |  |
| A2 | green |  | coffee | superman |

I've made lots of attempts at a solution, but can't get anything to work.

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try below

```
create temp table tmp as ( 
  select id, 
    translate(json_value(response, '$.Question'), " '?", "_") question,
    json_value(response, '$.Answer') answer
  from your_table, unnest(json_extract_array(response_group)) response
);

execute immediate (
  select 'select * from tmp pivot (any_value(answer) for question in (' || 
  string_agg(distinct '"' || question || '"') || '))'
from tmp
);
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]

To test above I was using dummy data from your question

```
create temp table your_table as (
  select 'A1' id, '''[{"Answer":"blue","Question":"what's your favourite colour?"},{"Answer":"dogs","Question":"do you prefer dogs or cats?"},{"Answer":"coffee", "Question":"do you prefer tea or coffee?"}]''' response_group union all
  select 'A2', '''[{"Answer":"green","Question":"what's your favourite colour?"},{"Answer":"Superman","Question":"who's your favourite superhero?"},{"Answer":"coffee", "Question":"do you prefer tea or coffee?"}]'''
);
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Mikhail. I'm afraid the query is returning an error: Invalid EXECUTE IMMEDIATE sql string `select * from tmp pivot (any_value(answer) for question in (question1, question2 etc

Comment: as you see in my answer  - it worked for me.  make sure you test carefully first with dummy data  - added in my answer based on data presented in your question  - and only then test with your real data!

Comment: Also, as you see in my answer - I am "escaping" some characters that are not allowed in the column name  - I escaped only those I saw in your example  - you might want to extend this piece of logic to cover all such not allowed chars - which should be trivial!

Comment: Thanks again for the quick reply. I'll try again - it must be something I'm doing wrong.

Comment: actually, I think you may have pointed me to a solution. A couple of the questions aren't in Latin script so I'm assuming BQ won't allow them as field names

Comment: correct. - that's definitely will trigger error